# LLVM's ExecutionEngine::runFunction passes wrong parameters to function. Why?

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm learning LLVM by implementing my own toy language, now I've come across a problem where I'm unable to call my generated functions when the function takes multiple arguments. Following is the simplest reproduction example I've come across so far (unoptimized IR for a function taking two arguments and returning the value of the second argument):

```
define i32 @Test_twoArg(i32 %a, i32 %b) {
entry:
  %b2 = alloca i32
  %a1 = alloca i32
  %returnValue = alloca i32
  store i32 %a, i32* %a1
  store i32 %b, i32* %b2
  %b3 = load i32* %b2, !dbg !8
  store i32 %b3, i32* %returnValue, !dbg !8
  br label %exit, !dbg !8

exit:                                             ; preds = %entry
  %returnValue4 = load i32* %returnValue, !dbg !9
  ret i32 %returnValue4, !dbg !9
}
```

my google-test code looks like this where the dump function produces the output above:

```
TEST_F(BinaryOperatorTest, TwoArg) {
  compileFunction("int twoArg(int a, int b) { return b; }");
  ASSERT_NE((llvm::Module *)NULL, m_module);

  llvm::Function *llvmFunction = m_module->getFunction("Test_twoArg");
  ASSERT_NE((llvm::Function *)NULL, llvmFunction);

  llvmFunction->dump();

  std::vector<llvm::GenericValue> arguments(2);
  arguments[0].IntVal = llvm::APInt(32, 11);
  arguments[1].IntVal = llvm::APInt(32, 13);
  llvm::GenericValue res
    = m_executionEngine->runFunction(llvmFunction, arguments);
  EXPECT_EQ(13, res.IntVal);
}
```

and this fails with:

```
binaryoperator_test.cpp:129: Failure
Value of: res.IntVal
  Actual: 16-byte object <20-00 00-00 8B-7F 00-00 20-00 00-00 00-00 00-00>
Expected: 13
```

if I modify the test to only take one argument as input and returning that argument then it works. I've used lldb to check the generated code and it looks valid (but un-optimal):

```
(lldb) disassemble
   0x7ffff7ff4000 <Test_twoArg>: movl   %edi, -0x8(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff4004 <Test_twoArg+4>: movl   %esi, -0x4(%rsp)
-> 0x7ffff7ff4008 <Test_twoArg+8>: movl   %esi, -0xc(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7ff400c <Test_twoArg+12>: movl   -0xc(%rsp), %eax
   0x7ffff7ff4010 <Test_twoArg+16>: retq
```

but the register values are wrong (`%rsi` and `%rdi` should contain 11 and 13):

```
(lldb) register read
General Purpose Registers:
       rax = 0x0000000000a48fef  unittests`llvm::MCJIT::runFunction(llvm::Function*, std::vector<llvm::GenericValue, std::allocator<llvm::GenericValue> > const&) + 399
       rbx = 0x00007fffffffdb70
       rcx = 0x0000000000000000
       rdx = 0xffffffffffc3469f
       rdi = 0x0000000001229328
       rsi = 0x0000000000000020
       rbp = 0x0000000000000020
       rsp = 0x00007fffffffda38
        r8 = 0x0000000000000000
        r9 = 0x0000000000000003
       r10 = 0x0000000000000001
       r11 = 0x0000000000000088
       r12 = 0x00007ffff7ff4000  JIT(0x12526d0)`Test_twoArg at unittest.dw:1
       r13 = 0x0000000001229328
       r14 = 0x0000000001249690
       r15 = 0x00007fffffffdb50
       rip = 0x00007ffff7ff4008  JIT(0x12526d0)`Test_twoArg + 8 at unittest.dw:1
    rflags = 0x0000000000000246
        cs = 0x0000000000000033
        fs = 0x0000000000000000
        gs = 0x0000000000000000
        ss = 0x000000000000002b
        ds = 0x0000000000000000
        es = 0x0000000000000000
```

So it looks like I'm calling runFunction in a wrong way but I can't figure out how, or is this a LLVM bug? Running LLVM-3.6 on Ubuntu, x86-64.

**UPDATE:**
By extracting the function pointer I am able to call the function correctly, so this seems more like a bug in runFunction:

```
  int (*function)(int, int) = (int (*)(int, int))m_executionEngine->getPointerToFunction(llvmFunction);
  int resi = function(11, 13);
  EXPECT_EQ(13, resi); // works
```

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a problem with calling runFunction when using MCJIT, by switching to a interpreter as execution engine everything works as expected. The problem can be seen [here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/MCJIT_8cpp_source.html#l00468): where only some combinations of return- and argument-types are handled. Since LLVM is compiled in NDEBUG, the llvm_unreachable call at the end is [removed and replaced by a hint that the code can't be reached](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/ErrorHandling_8h.html#ace243f5c25697a1107cce46626b3dc94) (this should probably be handled in a better way since it is probably why I can put break points inside the generated function).

Comment: Seems to be fixed on llvm-trunk.